# google maps listener only running once

Tags: javascript, google-maps, addeventlistener

I am having some difficulties where my listeners appear to cancel each other out only when I set a rectangle to the map, but not when I call an alert or anything else.

This works perfectly:

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("overlay" + me), 'click', function () {
    displayMessage(me); //displays the current overlay index on screen (IE 1 of 30)
});
```

The above simply displays the index of the overlay on the map (IE 1 of 30). It works at every overlay clicked with the proper overlay index.

This not so much:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("overlay" + me), 'click', function () {

    alert("Called");
    curOverlayRectangle.setOptions(overlayRectangleOptions); //defined by C# to js
    curOverlayRectangle.setBounds(incomingOverlayBounds[me]);
    curOverlayRectangle.setMap(map);
    alert("Finished");

});
```

The above is supposed to add a rectangle over the overlay already on the map. What it actually does is add the rectangle for the first overlay clicked, but then if I click another overlay, nothing happens.

It appears that the listener is never called because once I click the first overlay, it goes through and says finished with the rectangle drawn. I then proceed to click another overlay and no alert occurs...

I have been working on this for quite some time, please help! Thanks!

EDIT1:

```
//get is simply the index
function tempAddListener(get) {

    //alert("adding: " + get);
    if (document.getElementById("overlay" + get) != null) { //check to see if div is there
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("overlay" + get), 'click', function () {

            displayMessage("listener fired at overlay: " + get); //if enabled, works fine
            //displayOverlayRectangle(incomingOverlayBounds[get]); //if enabled, listener fires but seems to delete all my other listeners for the overlays

        });
    } else {
        //could not find the div
    } 

}
```

**Edit2**

```
//took out all defines

//#region geoObjs
var incomingOverlayBounds = [];
var incomingOverlaySourceURL = [];
var incomingOverlayRotation = [];
var incomingOverlayRectangle = [];
function initOverlays(){
  //most of these are taken out
  incomingOverlayBounds[0] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( new google.maps.LatLng(29.7883456702236,-82.384843759249), new 
  incomingOverlayRotation[16] = 0;
  incomingOverlayBounds[17] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( new google.maps.LatLng(29.4715356702236,-82.3839748493845), new google.maps.LatLng(29.51265,-82.33674));
  incomingOverlaySourceURL[17] = "http://ufdcimages.uflib.ufl.edu/UF/00/07/17/26/00027/12001_1968_2KK_20.jpg";
  incomingOverlayRotation[17] = 0;
  incomingOverlayBounds[18] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( new google.maps.LatLng(29.4584356702236,-82.3840587432067), new google.maps.LatLng(29.49955,-82.33683));
  incomingOverlaySourceURL[18] = "http://ufdcimages.uflib.ufl.edu/UF/00/07/17/26/00027/12001_1968_2KK_21.jpg";
  incomingOverlayRotation[18] = 0;
  incomingOverlayBounds[19] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( new google.maps.LatLng(29.4431556702236,-82.4158516259991), new google.maps.LatLng(29.48427,-82.36863));
  incomingOverlaySourceURL[19] = "http://ufdcimages.uflib.ufl.edu/UF/00/07/17/26/00027/12001_1968_2KK_022.jpg";
  incomingOverlayRotation[19] = 0;
  incomingOverlayBounds[20] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( new google.maps.LatLng(29.4593656702236,-82.4157191765652), new google.maps.LatLng(29.50048,-82.36849));
  incomingOverlaySourceURL[20] = "http://ufdcimages.uflib.ufl.edu/UF/00/07/17/26/00027/12001_1968_2KK_023.jpg";
  incomingOverlayRotation[20] = 0;
  incomingOverlayBounds[21] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( new google.maps.LatLng(29.4736856702236,-82.4151858519302), new google.maps.LatLng(29.5148,-82.36795));
  incomingOverlaySourceURL[21] = "http://ufdcimages.uflib.ufl.edu/UF/00/07/17/26/00027/12001_1968_2KK_024.jpg";
  incomingOverlayRotation[21] = 0;
  incomingOverlaySourceURL[51] = "http://ufdcimages.uflib.ufl.edu/UF/00/07/17/26/00027/12001_1968_2KK_054.jpg";
  incomingOverlayRotation[51] = 0;

  displayIncomingOverlays();

}
//#endregion        


function initialize() {
    //initialize google map objects
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(gmapPageDivId), gmapOptions);                             //initialize map    
    initOverlays(); //initialize all the incoming overlays
}

var incomingOverlayBounds = [];
var incomingOverlaySourceURL = [];
var incomingOverlayRotation = [];
var overlays = [];
function displayIncomingOverlays() {
    for (var i = 0; i < incomingOverlayBounds.length; i++) {
        overlaysOnMap[i] = new CustomOverlay(incomingOverlayBounds[i], incomingOverlaySourceURL[i], map, incomingOverlaySourceURL[i]);
        overlaysOnMap[i].setMap(map);

        //displayOverlayRectangle(incomingOverlayBounds[i]); //add all the rectangles
    }
}

function CustomOverlay(bounds, image, map, rotation) {
    //iterate here
    overlayCount++;

    // Now initialize all properties.
    this.bounds_ = bounds;
    this.image_ = image;
    this.map_ = map;

    preservedRotation = rotation;

    if (overlayPrevious != null) {
        overlayPrevious.setMap(null);
    }

    // We define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
    // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
    // method so we'll leave it null for now.
    this.div_ = null;
}
CustomOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function () {

    if (overlayPrevious != null) {
        overlayPrevious.setMap(null);
    }

    // Note: an overlay's receipt of onAdd() indicates that
    // the map's panes are now available for attaching
    // the overlay to the map via the DOM.

    // Create the DIV and set some basic attributes.
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "overlay" + overlaysOnMap.indexOf(this);
    div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
    div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.opacity = preserveOpacity;

    // Create an IMG element and attach it to the DIV.
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = incomingOverlaySourceURL[overlaysOnMap.indexOf(this)]; //this.image
    img.style.width = '100%';
    img.style.height = '100%';
    img.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.appendChild(img);

    //get the index
    var overlayIndex = overlaysOnMap.indexOf(this);

    // Set the overlay's div_ property to this DIV
    this.div_ = div;

    // We add an overlay to a map via one of the map's panes.
    // We'll add this overlay to the overlayLayer pane.
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);

    //add the listener
    tempAddListener(overlayIndex);

};
CustomOverlay.prototype.draw = function () {
    // Size and position the overlay. We use a southwest and northeast
    // position of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
    // We need to retrieve the projection from this overlay to do this.
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

    // Retrieve the southwest and northeast coordinates of this overlay
    // in latlngs and convert them to pixels coordinates.
    // We'll use these coordinates to resize the DIV.
    var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
    var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

    // Resize the image's DIV to fit the indicated dimensions.
    var div = this.div_;
    div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
    div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
    div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
    div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';

    //for a preserved rotation
    if (preservedRotation != 0) {
        //keepRotate(preservedRotation);
    }
};
//CustomOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function () {
//    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
//    this.div_ = null;
//};
function tempAddListener(get) {
    alert("div: "+document.getElementById("overlay" + get).innerHTML);
    alert("adding with index: " + get);
    if (document.getElementById("overlay" + get) != null) { //check to see if div is there
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("overlay" + get), 'click', function () {

            alert("listener fired at overlay: " + get);

            displayOverlayRectangle(incomingOverlayBounds[get]);
            //alert(incomingOverlayBounds[get]);


            //overlayRectangles[get] = displayOverlayRectangle(incomingOverlayBounds[get]);
            //overlayRectangles[get].setMap(map);

        });
    } else {
        //could not find the div
    } 

}

function displayOverlayRectangle(bounds) {
    //2do: set drawing manager, set mode, match listeners of rectangle
    var tempOverlayRectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle();
    var tempOverlayRectangleOptions = {
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
        editable: true,
        draggable: true,
        //strokeOpacity: 0.2,
        //strokeWeight: 1,
        //fillOpacity: 0.0, 
        zindex: 5 
    };

    tempOverlayRectangle.setOptions(tempOverlayRectangleOptions);
    tempOverlayRectangle.setBounds(bounds);
    tempOverlayRectangle.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(tempOverlayRectangle, "click", function () {
        alert("can't touch this");
    });

    //return tempOverlayRectangle;

    //tempOverlayRectangle.setOptions(tempOverlayRectangleOptions);
    //tempOverlayRectangle.setBounds(bounds);
    //tempOverlayRectangle.setMap(map);
}



//start this whole mess once 
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

<div id="googleMap"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

It appears that any map code on the listener will invalidate the other listeners. (IE I tried it with the following code and it still only ran once)

```
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("overlay" + get), 'click', function () {

            if (map.getMapTypeId() == 'TERRAIN') {
                map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
            } else {
                map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
            }

        });
```

Comment: did you check the console? maybe an exception was thrown during the first call of a listener? (not exactly in the code above)

Comment: so in my Visual studio there are no errors. I am also using firebug and there is no error. I am baffled because if I remove the curOverlayRectangle.setMap(map), it fires every time but when it is there it only fires once.

Comment: So you don't create the curOverlayRectangle every time?
Probably this is a problem (rectangle is "registered" in the map and there could be some issues with modyfing the object). To manage rectangles you should also store them somewhere (for instance you would like to hide them at some point of time). 
Try after first alert create the object from the beginning:
curOverlayRectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle();
and then proceed with the rest of the method.

Comment: I do exactly that in my global var defines. The odd thing is that everything works with the first listener. If I add the bit about actually putting the rectangle down, the listener only runs once -or appears to.

I've changed the code a bit where I have a function to create the rectangle and test the whole thing to see if the div (the overlay itself) is there

Comment: But when do you create a new reactangle? You should do it every time when listener is called. Can you post the whole html without irrelevant content?

Comment: I've posted most of the bare bones code... It will not validate but you can see the jest.

I call a fcn each time the listener is called. 

ignore that timeout fcn, I was just trying it out. uncomment //add the listener
  //tempAddListener(overlayIndex);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Bottom line, the overlay I was creating could not be accessed appropriately by the DOM. Thus, I created an invisible rectangle to overlay on top of my overlay which can be accessed.

**Snippet:**

```
    var incomingOverlayBounds = [];         //defined in c# to js on page
var incomingOverlaySourceURL = [];      //defined in c# to js on page
var incomingOverlayRotation = [];       //defined in c# to js on page
var ghostOverlayRectangle = [];         //holds ghost overlay rectangles (IE overlay hotspots)
var ghostOverlayRectangleOptions = {    //define options for ghost rectangle
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",             //color doesnt matter
    strokeOpacity: 0.0,                 //make border invisible
    strokeWeight: 1,                    //should not matter?
    fillColor: "#FF0000",               //color doesnt matter
    fillOpacity: 0.0,                   //make fill transparent
    editable: false,                    //just to be sure?
    draggable: false,                   //just to be sure?
    zindex: 6                           //perhaps higher?
};
var visibleOverlayRectangleOptions = {  //define options for visible rectangle 
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",             //for testing (red)
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,                 //for testing
    strokeWeight: 2,                    //for testing
    fillColor: "#FF0000",               //for testing (red)
    fillOpacity: 0.1,                   //for testing
    editable: true,                     //sobek standard
    draggable: true,                    //sobek standard
    //strokeOpacity: 0.2,              //sobek standard
    //strokeWeight: 1,                 //sobek standard
    //fillOpacity: 0.0,                   //sobek standard 
    zindex: 5                           //sobek standard
};
var visibleOverlayRectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle(); //init maybe move to array later

//Displays all the overlays sent from the C# code. Also calls displayGhostOverlayRectangle.
function displayIncomingOverlays() {
    //go through and display overlays as long as there is an overlay to display
    for (var i = 0; i < incomingOverlayBounds.length; i++) {
        overlaysOnMap[i] = new CustomOverlay(incomingOverlayBounds[i], incomingOverlaySourceURL[i], map, incomingOverlayRotation[i]);
        overlaysOnMap[i].setMap(map);                                               //set the overlay to the map
        displayGhostOverlayRectangle(incomingOverlayBounds[i],i);                   //add all the ghost rectangles
    }
}

//Displays an invisible rectangle on top of the overlay div (creates a hotspot). This rectangle is used as a psuedo listener if the 'overlay div' is clicked. This solved issue of creating listener for overlay div directly.
//Supporting URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025240/google-maps-listener-only-running-once
function displayGhostOverlayRectangle(ghostBounds,ghostIndex) {
    ghostOverlayRectangle[ghostIndex] = new google.maps.Rectangle();                //init rect
    ghostOverlayRectangle[ghostIndex].setOptions(ghostOverlayRectangleOptions);     //set options
    ghostOverlayRectangle[ghostIndex].setBounds(ghostBounds);                       //set bounds
    ghostOverlayRectangle[ghostIndex].setMap(map);                                  //set to map
    //create the listener for this ghost rectangle
    google.maps.event.addListener(ghostOverlayRectangle[ghostIndex], 'click', function () {
        displayVisibleOverlayRectangle(ghostBounds, ghostIndex);                    //add the visible rectangles
    });
}

//Displays the visible rectangle which is used to edit an overlay. Called by the ghost listener.    
function displayVisibleOverlayRectangle(bounds, overlayIndex) {
    visibleOverlayRectangle.setOptions(visibleOverlayRectangleOptions);
    visibleOverlayRectangle.setBounds(bounds);
    visibleOverlayRectangle.setMap(map);
}

//Starts the creation of a custom overlay div which contains a rectangular image.
//Supporting URL: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays
function CustomOverlay(bounds, image, map, rotation) {
    overlayCount++;                 //iterate how many overlays have been drawn
    this.bounds_ = bounds;          //set the bounds
    this.image_ = image;            //set source url
    this.map_ = map;                //set to map
    preservedRotation = rotation;   //set the rotation
    this.div_ = null;               //defines a property to hold the image's div. We'll actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd() method so we'll leave it null for now.
}

//Continues support for adding an custom overlay
//Supporting URL: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays
// Note: an overlay's receipt of onAdd() indicates that the map's panes are now available for attaching the overlay to the map via the DOM.
CustomOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function () {

    // Create the DIV and set some basic attributes.
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "overlay" + overlaysOnMap.indexOf(this);
    div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
    div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.opacity = preserveOpacity;

    // Create an IMG element and attach it to the DIV.
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = incomingOverlaySourceURL[overlaysOnMap.indexOf(this)]; //this.image
    img.style.width = '100%';
    img.style.height = '100%';
    img.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.appendChild(img);

    // Set the overlay's div_ property to this DIV
    this.div_ = div; 

    // We add an overlay to a map via one of the map's panes.
    // We'll add this overlay to the overlayLayer pane.
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);     
};

//Continues support for adding an custom overlay
//Supporting URL: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays
CustomOverlay.prototype.draw = function () {
    // Size and position the overlay. We use a southwest and northeast
    // position of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
    // We need to retrieve the projection from this overlay to do this.
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

    // Retrieve the southwest and northeast coordinates of this overlay
    // in latlngs and convert them to pixels coordinates.
    // We'll use these coordinates to resize the DIV.
    var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
    var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

    // Resize the image's DIV to fit the indicated dimensions.
    var div = this.div_;
    div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
    div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
    div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
    div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';

    //for a preserved rotation
    if (preservedRotation != 0) {
        keepRotate(preservedRotation);
    }
};

//Not currently used
//Supporting URL: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays
CustomOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function () {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
};
```